# how can i set gravity to right for row recyclerview

Tags: android

I want to set gravity to right in my recyclerview
,I set to right gravity for all layout but when horizontal recyclerview has one row, it do not set gravity to right
see picture to understand me [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSePd.jpg)

I want red circle in picture set gravity to right.

my CityDetailACT activity:

```
package safarkon.com.safarkon.cityDetail;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import safarkon.com.safarkon.R;

public class CityDetailACT extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerViewDataAdapter rAdapterBazar;
    ArrayList<SectionDataModelRecyclerModel> allSampleData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.city_detail_act);

        allSampleData = new ArrayList<SectionDataModelRecyclerModel>();
        rvListBazar.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvListBazar.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        rAdapterBazar = new RecyclerViewDataAdapter(CityDetailACT.this, allSampleData);
        rvListBazar.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        rvListBazar.setAdapter(rAdapterBazar);

        createDummyData();

    }

    public void createDummyData() {
        for (int i = 2; i <= 8; i++) {
            SectionDataModelRecyclerModel dm = new SectionDataModelRecyclerModel();

            String cat = null;
            if (i == 1){
                //cat = "بدانید";
                dm.setHeaderTitle("هر آنچه درمورد "+city+" باید بدانید");

            }else if (i == 2){
                cat = "بازار";
                dm.setHeaderTitle("بازارهای "+city);
            }else if (i == 3){
                cat = "دیدنی";
                dm.setHeaderTitle("معرفی مکانهای گردشگری "+city);
            }else if (i == 4){
                cat = "تاریخی";
                dm.setHeaderTitle("دیدنی های تاریخی "+city);
            }else if (i == 5){
                cat = "پارک";
                dm.setHeaderTitle("پارک های "+city);
            }else if (i == 6){
                cat = "مسجد";
                dm.setHeaderTitle("مسجدها و امام زاده های "+city);
            }else if (i == 7){
                cat = "موزه";
                dm.setHeaderTitle("موزه های "+city);
            }else if (i == 8){
                cat = "مدرسه";
                dm.setHeaderTitle("مدرسه های "+city);
            }
            ArrayList<RecyclerModel> singleItem = new ArrayList<RecyclerModel>();

            LoadData.firstLoadData(this,rAdapterBazar,singleItem,rvListBazar);

            dm.setAllItemsInSection(singleItem);
            allSampleData.add(dm);
        }
    }

}
```

RecyclerViewDataAdapter:

```
package safarkon.com.safarkon.cityDetail;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import safarkon.com.safarkon.R;
    public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {

        private ArrayList<SectionDataModelRecyclerModel> dataList;
        private Context mContext;

        public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SectionDataModelRecyclerModel> dataList) {
            this.dataList = dataList;
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_row_nested_list, null);
            ItemRowHolder mh = new ItemRowHolder(v);
            return mh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, int i) {

            final String sectionName = dataList.get(i).getHeaderTitle();

            ArrayList singleSectionItems = dataList.get(i).getAllItemsInSection();

            itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(sectionName);

            RecyclerAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(singleSectionItems,"a",mContext);

            itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
            itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
            itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
            itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL));
            itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);
            itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return (null != dataList ? dataList.size() : 0);
        }

        public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            protected TextView itemTitle;

            protected RecyclerView recycler_view_list;

            protected TextView txMore;



            public ItemRowHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

                this.itemTitle =  view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
                this.recycler_view_list =view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);
                this.txMore=  view.findViewById(R.id.txMore);


            }

        }

    }
```

RecyclerAdapter:

```
package safarkon.com.safarkon.cityDetail;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.iarcuschin.simpleratingbar.SimpleRatingBar;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import safarkon.com.safarkon.R;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<RecyclerModel> recyclerModels; // this data structure carries our title and description
    Context c;
    String rowLayoutType;
    int width;
    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerModel> recyclerModels,String rowLayoutType, Context c) {
        this.recyclerModels = recyclerModels;
        this.rowLayoutType = rowLayoutType;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerModel> recyclerModels,String rowLayoutType, Context c,int width) {
        this.recyclerModels = recyclerModels;
        this.rowLayoutType = rowLayoutType;
        this.c = c;
        this.width = width;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_city_detail, parent, false));

    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder holder,final int position) {

            Picasso.with(c)
                    .load(recyclerModels.get(position).getPicture())
                    .resize(width,0)
                    .into(holder.imageView);
            holder.tx_onvan.setText(recyclerModels.get(position).getOnvan());
            holder.tx_position.setText(recyclerModels.get(position).getPosition());
            holder.ratingBar.setRating((float)recyclerModels.get(position).getRate());
            holder.txCountRateAndComment.setText("( "+recyclerModels.get(position).getCountRateAndComment() + " نظر" + " )");

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recyclerModels.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txCountRateAndComment;;
        TextView tx_onvan;
        TextView tx_position;
        ImageView imageView;
        SimpleRatingBar ratingBar;
        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            tx_onvan=  itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
            tx_position=  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txPostion);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            ratingBar=  itemView.findViewById(R.id.simpleRatingBar);
            txCountRateAndComment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txCountRateAndComment);

        }
    }
}
```

city_detail_act:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top"

    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tolbar_story"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#66cc66"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgTooTitlelbarMainActf"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"


                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/adamak" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgTooTitlelbarMainAct"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"

                android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="181dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="181dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/title" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgNavigationView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/dot" />


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txMore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/adobearabicbold"
                    android:text="مشاهده همه..."
                    android:textSize="12sp"

                    />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txYHinCityDetail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/adobearabicbold"
                    android:text="هر آنچه درمورد قم باید بدانید"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvListBazar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want set gravity to right when horizontal recyclerview has only one row,
because when horizontal recyclerview has more one row it gravity set to right
,How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

In your RecyclerViewDataAdapter ,set the last parameter of the `setLayotManager` to false and if that does not work ,  set LinearLayoutManager.setStatckFromEnd property to true